# Can anybody explain what the component of x is?

Tags: matrices

I am going over how matrix is formed.

And, for $T: V \to W$

Where $V$ is $n$ dimension and $W$ is $m$ dimension.

When it defines $x$ in $V$ with linear combination, It multiplies basis for $V$ with components of $x$ relative to ordered basis.

What is a definition of components of $x$? and why do they not multiply basis with any scalars ?

I am confused.

I don't get the meaning of " components of x with relative to ordered basis.

Can anybody give me a concrete example of it?

Answer (score 0):

well if $x \in V$ and say $B=${$e_1,e_2,...,e_n$} is a basis of $V$, then by definition of basis , $x$ can be written as a linear combination of {$e_1,e_2,...,e_n$} i.e. $x=a_1e_1+a_2e_2+......+a_ne_n$ where $a_i \in F$, the field acting on $V$. Here by components w.r.t he means these scalars $a_1,a_2...,a_n$. well a vector space can have many basis, so for every basis these scalars will be diffrent, that is why he uses "with respect to" some particular basis

$\textbf{EXAMPLE-}$ 
Consider vector space $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ , one basis is {$1,i$} another is {${1,-i}$}. Now coordinates of $-i$ w.r.t first are {$0,-1$} but w.r.t second are {$0,1$}